# search for a particular tag and replace its value

Tags: xml, perl, file

I need to search for  tag having value h:mm:ss and replace this value with h hours, mm minutes, and ss seconds to my outputfile.

I am struggling with the replace syntax. write now I am having an input file to read on.

here is what i am trying -

```
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filein)
  or die "Could not open file '$filein' $!";

while(<$fh>) {
   chomp $_;
   while ( $_ =~ /<time>\s*([^<]*)\s*<\/time>/g ) {
      chomp $1; 
      push(@time, $1);
   }
}
close($fh);

open(my $wr, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filein)
  or die "Could not open file '$filein' $!";

open(FILE, ">$fileout") or die "File not found";

print FILE "average time = 1:00:43\n";

while (my $line = <>){
   $line =~ m!/s/[%d:%02d:%02d]/g/hacker/!; #hacker is my replaced value for testing purpose.
    #$x =~ s/cat/hacker/;
   #s/<PREF>/ABCD/g;
   print FILE $line;
   }
print FILE @time;
close(FILE);
```

Comment: `perl -pe 's/(\d):(\d{2}):(\d{2})/$1 hours $2 minutes, and $3 seconds/g' infile > outfile` perhaps.

Comment: What is `m!/s/[%d:%02d:%02d]/g/hacker/!`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
assuming that `$newh`, `$newmin` and `$newsec` are new values for hours, minutes and seconds respectively.

```
$line =~ s/\d+:\d\d:\d\d/$newh:$newmin:$newsec/g;
```

You can also combine the "new" variables in one:

```
my $new_time="$newh:$newmin:$newsec";
$line =~ s/\d+:\d\d:\d\d/$new_time/g;
```

Explanations:

`\d+` - one or more decimal digits
`:` - just a colon
`\d` - exactly one decimal digit